# Where does the following series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Using integrals or by any other method find:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i}$

Comment: Series, not 'serie'.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1 {n+i}
=
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1n\,\frac1 {1+\frac in} \to\int_0^1\frac1 {1+x}\,dx=\log2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Martin Argerami gave the simplest solution using integrals.

Using another method and admitting that you already heard about [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1 {n+i}=H_{2 n}-H_n$$ Now, using their asymptotic expansions (given in the Wikipedia page) $$S_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

For illustration purposes, let us use $n=10$. The exact result would be $$S_{10}=\frac{155685007}{232792560}\approx 0.6687714$$ while the above approximation would give $\approx 0.6687722$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i}
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}\\
&\to (\ln(2n)+\gamma)-(\ln(n)+\gamma)\\
&=\ln(2)\\
\end{array}
$